# Check if list of dictionaries are unique based on a property

Tags: python, dictionary, properties, unique

Is there a function in the python standard library to check if a list is unique based on one of the dictionary properties?

Something like this:

```
is_unique(dict_list, prop="x")
```

**result:**

```
{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, {"x": 2, "y": 3}  <- False
{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 3}  <- True
```

Comment: Do you know that prop will be in all the dicts?

Comment: yes its in all the dicts

Comment: *"best"* by what criteria? What's your current implementation, and what do you think the problem with it is?

Comment: ok not necessarily the best... don't want to write my own if python has one already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can naively do:

```
def is_unique(dcts, prop):
    return len(dcts) == len(set(d[prop] for d in dcts))
```

This assumes that the values `d[prop]` are hashable. If you have long lists, you might want to break early (when encountering the first duplicate) while building the prop set, as does 
U9-Forward's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
def is_unique(lod, prop):
    seen=set()
    return not any(i[prop] in seen or seen.add(i[prop]) for i in lod)
LOD=[{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, {"x": 2, "y": 3}]
print(is_unique(LOD,'x'))
```

Output:

```
False
```